# How can I locate a file to use with the system/child_process API within a Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to write a Firefox add-on that communicates with a locally installed program to exchange data. It looks like this can be done using either [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) or the low-level [system/child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) API, with the latter being the [recommended solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.extensions/sZC9l9zR-tM/DGx2UxGpEgAJ).

The child_process API appeals because it sends and receives data abstractly over a pipe rather than directly at the C interface level. However, to use it you need (it seems) to supply the full path to the executable within your code:

```
var child_process = require("sdk/system/child_process");
var ls = child_process.spawn('/bin/ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
```

In my case, the executable is installed by another application and we don't know it's exact location - it will differ according to OS, the user's drives, and possibly the user's preference. I imagine this problem will be common to most executables that are not built in to the OS. So my question is: what means do I have to locate the full path of the executable I want to use? I will need to support multiple OSes but presumably could have different solutions for each if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to iterate expected locations. Lots of common loctions are listed in `OS.Constants.Path`, like desktop etc. You can always have the user provide the location. You can get Environment information - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_environment

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file - shows you how to list files in a directory. child_process is written in js-ctypes itself. Don't rewrite it haha

Comment: Well, how do other applications find the exact location? Is it in the `PATH` or some other environment variable? Is there some configuration file in the user's home dir?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Noitidart. I guess I wasn't expecting my extension to be able to access the file system quite as easily! In the end I am using `system/env` to get access to the "programfiles(x86)" environment variable, then using `io/file` to construct a path to my binary (I will work out the Mac particulars later but will end up using a similar approach I'm sure). If you would like to submit an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It would be awesome if you could post up the code you used as a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I used on Windows - the key was being able to read an environment variable to find the location of the appropriate application folder. After that I assume that my application is stored under a well-known subpath (we don't allow customization of it).

```
var system = require("sdk/system");
var iofile = require('sdk/io/file');
var child_process = require('sdk/system/child_process');

var progFilesFolder = system.env["programfiles(x86)"],
    targetFile = iofile.join(progFilesFolder, 'FolderName', 'Program.exe');
    targetFileExists = iofile.exists(targetFile);

if (targetFileExists) {
    var p = child_process.spawn(targetFile);
}
```

I haven't written the code for Mac yet but I expect it to be similar, with the difference being that there are no drive letters to worry about and the system folders in OS X have standard names (even on localized systems).